# Caps Lock key is not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, capslock

**I recently upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.**

After upgrading Everything is OK. But while I am typing password during login caps lock key is not working.I am trying to write uppercase character but it's still showing lowercase character.

Example Image
[image: Example Image]

I've looked into the forum for solution but it's not working. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may rather be a feature than a bug. An activated <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> has most likely been the cause of many troubles during the login process. Windows, for example, explicitly notifies you if the <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> key is activated.

Just imagine that the <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> key is unknowingly activated while you type in your password...

Comment: No, that's not the real problem. I updated the topic. I am trying to write uppercase character but after pressing caps lock key, it's still showing in lowercase character.

Comment: What I was trying to say: maybe it's deactivated intentionally on the login screen.